# Interesting numbers when apache benchmarking

Tags: apache-httpd, testing

```
[root@NOTEBOOK ~] time for i in 128 321; do sleep 302; ab -n $i -c $i https://EXAMPLE.COM/ 2>/dev/null | egrep '^Complete requests:|^Failed requests:|^Requests per second:|^Time taken for tests:'; echo '______________________'; done
Time taken for tests:   87.538 seconds
Complete requests:      128
Failed requests:        0
Requests per second:    1.46 [#/sec] (mean)
______________________
Time taken for tests:   58.507 seconds
Complete requests:      321
Failed requests:        490
Requests per second:    5.49 [#/sec] (mean)
______________________
```

**Q:** how could the Failed requests > Complete requests?

p.s.: The "sleep 302" is needed, because somehow if I do too many ab's then the outputs will be 100% fails..

Comment: The answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/7657896/2618565 on stackoverflow.com may be helpful.

Comment: please post it as answer or duplicate, Thanks!